# How to provide dynamic database configuration credentials for Spark Java?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, spark-java

I'm building a simple REST API using spark java. The project uses `Postgres` DB for storage, `gradle` as the build system. The fat Jar is deployed on `AWS`.

I have three environments `local`, `staging` & `production`. For each fat jar creation, I wanna provide specific configuration like the below one used for local builds:

```
    dbHost = "localhost"
    dbUsername = "myusername"
    dbPassword = "mypassword"
    database = "mydb"
    dbPort = "5432"
```

How to provide these values dynamically based on fatJar build variant?

Comment: How about a properties file for each? For example `config-local.properties`, `config-production.properties`, etc

Comment: @k.liakos Thanks for the tip :) I'd already solved the issue by following the same path. I'd given a detailed solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd used `.properties` file to by following this sample github project [Kotlin-dev-proxy](https://github.com/IRus/kotlin-dev-proxy).

The server reads the  environmental variable called `app_environment` and uses the appropriate resource file.

**Sample Code:**

**DbConfig.kt**

```
data class DbConfig(
        val dbHost: String,
        val dbUsername: String,
        val dbPassword: String,
        val dbName: String,
        val dbPort: Int)
```

**ServerSettings.kt**

```
class ServerSettings(settings: String) {
    val resources = Properties()

    init {
        val fileUrl: URL = resources.javaClass.getResource("/$settings.properties")
                ?: throw FileNotFoundException("$settings.properties file not found")
        fileUrl.openStream().use { resources.load(it) }
    }

    fun printSettings() = resources.stringPropertyNames().forEach {
        println("Property: $it has value: '${resources[it]}'")
    }

    fun getString(key: String): String = resources[key]!! as String

    fun getInt(key: String): Int = (resources[key]!! as String).toInt()
}
```

**DbConfig.kt**

```
fun provideDbConfig(): DbConfig {
        val settings = ServerSettings(System.getenv("app_environment"))
        settings.printSettings()

        return DbConfig(
                dbHost = settings.getString("dbHost"),
                dbUsername = settings.getString("dbUsername"),
                dbPassword = settings.getString("dbPassword"),
                dbName = settings.getString("dbName"),
                dbPort = settings.getInt("dbPort")
        )
    }
```

**resources/develop.properties**

```
# Local Db values
dbHost=localhost
dbUsername=postgresusername
dbPassword=postgrespassword
dbName=mydbname
dbPort=5432
```

While deploying in Amazon EBS, goto software configuration and add the environmental variable appropriate(staging/production) for the environment.